# iFrame content refuses to load on iOS browsers only - even though a Content-Security-Policy (CSP) frame-ancestors directive is issued

Tags: ios, iframe, mobile, cross-browser, content-security-policy

I am creating a website (Site A) in a simple Content Management System. Because the CMS cannot interact with my data server, I have some web content hosted on another web server (Site B - subdomain.example.com) that I display in an iFrame on Site A.

I have added the following content security policy via an HTTP response header on the web server hosting Site B:

`Content-Security-Policy:` `frame-ancestors *.example.com;`

Everything works well on my desktop machine (the iFrame content displays correctly in Chrome, Safari, Firefox). However, when I try to display Site A on my iPhone (iOS 17.1.2) the iFrame fails to display content in any browser of the mobile versions of the browsers above. Safari Web Inspector shows the following error:

> Refused to load https://subdomain.example.com/my-site because it does not appear in the frame-ancestors directive of the Content Security Policy

How can I modify the CSP directive so it will work in iOS?

I have tried replacing the wildcard with the subdomain name as well as including https//: in the path name - both without success. I have also searched online but have not found a solution to this particular issue. I do not have a CSP in the  element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of trial and error I finally discovered a solution. Here is a summary of syntax that works on iOS and what doesn't:

`frame-ancestors www.example.com;` Works on desktop but *not* iOS.

`frame-ancestors *.example.com;` Works on desktop but *not* iOS.

`frame-ancestors *;` Works on desktop *and* iOS **but** creates a security vulnerability (for illustration purposes only - don't use).

`frame-ancestors example.com;` Works on iOS but *not* desktop.

`frame-ancestors www.example.com example.com;` **Works on *both* desktop and iOS.

Summary:

- It appears that iOS recognizes the wildcard character (*) when used alone but not when used as part of a URL
- Including the www prefix causes iOS to refuse to load the iFrame content (even though the correct URL is https://www.example.com).
- The above applies to all iOS browsers tested (Safari, Chrome, Firefox).

Answer (score 3):

When you want to embed Site B in siteA, the path in the Content security policy of Site B should be the url of **site A** .

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors#sources

Comment: Good catch. The correct url is for the CSP is www.example.com, not subdomain.example.com. I had used a wildcard (*.example.com) which is why it was working on my Mac. I have now corrected it to www.example.com (the url of Site A). Same problem though - it still works on my Mac but not on any browser in iOS. I studied the documentation and tried different variations but cannot find the issue.

Comment: Could you share the error that you see now?

Comment: It is still giving me the same error as above